# What it means when PM(K) of ps gets negative values?

Tags: windows, powershell

I got the following negative PM (The amount of pageable memory that the process is using, in kilobytes) values when execute the `ps` command. What it means when the values are negative?

```
PS H:\> ps sqlservr

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
   5947    4145 -1218888    1537304   981 ...50.77   8344 sqlservr


PS H:\> ps sqlservr

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
   6060    4172 -1218876    1537316   981 ...52.08   8344 sqlservr


PS H:\> ps sqlservr

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
   6481    4258 -1218832    1537376   981 ...56.55   8344 sqlservr
```

The negative value may be the overflow of `Int32`? However, the following statements shows that the paged memory was 4TB? Which is not possible.

```
$m = [int32]::MaxValue
($m + ($m -1218832) + 2)/1024/1024
# returns 4094.83763122559 (GB)
```

Comment: Interesting question but I can't help but feel this might be better on ServerFault.

Comment: `PagedMemorySize` (which is what `PM` is an alias for) may be incorrect in a 64-bit environment, you really should be looking at `PagedMemorySize64` instead. Kind of a bummer that the default display set references the "wrong" value on 64-bit systems

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I tried to convert the negative number to int64 but it's a huge unreal number?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 I wouldn't spend too much time trying to "figure out" how they correspond, just accept that `PagedMemorySize` is not what you want. For all we know it might not be an integer overflow (could be a hard-coded limit, like 4GB, which would make sense for 32-bit systems)

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple signed/unsigned overflow error. It's overflowing both the negative space and (in many modern situations) overflowing the unsigned 32-bit range as well.

I believe all `PM(K)` is doing is showing `PagedMemorySize / 1024`.  They should be showing `PagedMemorySize64 / 1024`.

Here's what I get on my local server with 16GB of RAM and 14GB reserved for SQL Server:

```
PS C:\> $x = ps sqlservr
PS U:\> $x

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
   1555    1280 -1683524     132568    81            2056 sqlservr
PS U:\> $x.PagedMemorySize / 1024
-1683524
PS C:\> $x.PagedMemorySize
-1723928576
PS C:\> $x.PagedMemorySize.GetType().FullName
System.Int32
```

The guys who wrote `Get-Process` should have used unsigned integers, but didn't.

You can do the two's compliment math pretty easily, but it'll be pretty clear that the value still doesn't make sense because you've overflowed out of 32-bit address space entirely:

```
PS C:\> ($x.PagedMemorySize + [uint32]::MaxValue + 1) / 1GB
2.39446640014648
```

And you can prove out that the number takes more than 31 bits of address space pretty easily:

```
PS C:\> [math]::log($x.PagedMemorySize + [uint32]::MaxValue + 1)/[math]::log(2)
31.2597041913968
```

*[Note: I might have that wrong... I can never remember when to add the 1.]*

You should use `PagedMemorySize64 / 1024`:

```
PS C:\> $x.PagedMemorySize64.GetType().FullName
System.Int64
PS C:\> $x.PagedMemorySize64 / 1KB
15093692
PS C:\> $x.PagedMemorySize64 / 1GB
14.3944664001465
```

And you can prove out that you need more than 32 bits of address space as easily as we did above:

```
PS C:\> [math]::log($x.PagedMemorySize64)/[math]::log(2)
33.847442404377
```

So my system needs 34 of the 64 bits to address all the memory it's using.

You can even see where the 2.39 GB number from above comes from with a little binary math:

```
PS C:\> ($x.PagedMemorySize64 -band [uint32]::MaxValue) / 1GB
2.39446640014648
```

Technically, they *should* have used unsigned 64-bit integers for PagedMemorySize64, but it's pretty unlikely that you'll need that much address space for the foreseeable future (`[int64]::MaxValue / 1PB` = 8,192 petabytes).